# Passing References to Member Functions

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern, function-reference

I've been working with a doubly-threaded BST in C++, and I thought it would be cool to separate my visitor functions from my various traversals. However I can't figure out how to properly pass references to member functions into my traversal functions. Here is a massively simplified version of my problem:

```
class foo {
public:
    foo() {};
    ~foo() {};

    void print(int x) const { //visitor
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    void traverse(void (*visitor)(int)) { //traversal
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            visitor(myAry[i]);
    }

    void printAll() { //function calling the traversal and passing it a reference to the visitor
        traverse(&print);
    }

    int myAry[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
};
```

The problem of course comes in the `traverse(&print);` statement.

Any clues what's going wrong, or what I could try differently to achieve the same effect?

Comment: In case its of use, the errors are: 

E0167: "argument of type "void (foo::*)(int x) const" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)(int)""

C2276: "'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void (*visitor)(int)
```

In C++ this means: a pointer to a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns a `void`.

```
&print
```

The type of this expression is not "a pointer to a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns a `void`". It is "a pointer to a method of `class foo` that takes an `int` parameter and returns a `void`".

Class methods and functions are not the same thing. They might look the same, but they're not.

In your sample code you don't need to use a class method, for `print`, so just declare it as a `static` class member:

```
static void print(int x) const {
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

And, with no other changes, this should work, since this is now a function. The difference between a class method is a function is that a class method requires an object whose method gets invoked.

It's possible that your clear code does really require a pointer to a class method. In which case `traverse()` should probably be something like:

```
void traverse(void (*foo::visitor)(int)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        (this->*visitor)(myAry[i]);
}
```

and this would be invoked as

```
traverse(&foo::print);
```

This is because `void (*foo::visitor)(int)` means "a pointer to a method of `class foo` that takes an `int` parameter and returns a `void`". And this is what your `print` is.

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly. In the case of making `print()` into a `static` class member, how does that exactly prevent it from being a class method?

Comment: A class method is "something" that does "something" to an instance of its class. A static class member is not associated with any instance of its class. You should be able to find a more complete discussion of what's the difference between static and non-static class members in your C++ textbook.

Comment: Ouch, is it that obvious that I'm a student? ;) I kid, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the class and which instance to call the function on. Also make sure that the signatures match.

```
void traverse(void(foo::*visitor)(int) const) {
//                 ^^^^^               ^^^^^
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        (this->*visitor)(myAry[i]);
//       ^^^^^^
}

void printAll() {
    traverse(&foo::print);
//            ^^^^^
}
```

Comment: @ToTheStars_1138 You are welcome. A pointer to a member function doesn't carry information about any specific instance of the class, so you have to specify that. `this` in this case.