# Why can't a nonstatic member function be referred to using the dot operator without calling it?

Tags: c++, std

Consider the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Foo {
private:
    int m_num;
    char m_letter;

public:
    explicit Foo(int a, char c)
        : m_num(a), m_letter(c)
    {}

    int const& num() const { return m_num; }
    char const& letter() const { return m_letter; }

    void do_something(void) { 
        std::cout << m_num << ", " << m_letter << "\n";
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Foo foo(7, 'z');

    // Doesn't compile
    // std::function<void(void)> member_func1 = foo.do_something; 
    
    std::function<void(void)> member_func2 = [&foo]() -> auto {
        foo.do_something();
    };

    std::function<void(Foo&)> member_func3 = std::mem_fn(&Foo::do_something);
}
```

If I try and compile the line that has been commented out, the error message is clear: `reference to non-static member function must be called`.

The two workarounds I've found are used to set `member_func2` and `member_func3`, and are fairly intuitive.

1. For `member_func2`, we create a very thin lambda wrapper that captures the target object by reference, and in the body calls the object's member function we are interested in.
2. For `member_func3`, we utilize `std::mem_fn` to create a `std::function<void(Foo&)>`. This also appears to also be a wrapping function that takes the target object by reference as the first parameter, and then invokes its member function we are interested within its `operator()()` function. The type signature on `member_func3` is very reminiscent of c-style parameter conventions.

**Now that the setup is complete, here is my main point:**

It would be really nice to be able to just write

```
auto member_func = foo.do_something;
```

rather than needing to call out to larger constructs (lambdas and `std::mem_fn`).

What is the reason for this design? Is there an underlying reason in the standard that prevents this? Is it computationally difficult or even impossible to do this with only the information provided to the compiler in the line above?

Any illumination on this subject is appreciated.

Comment: What type would you assign to the expression `foo.do_something`? There are two things being collected, as you can see in your "workarounds" -- the function `Foo::do_something()` and the object `foo`. *Note that the qualified function name uses the name of the class, not the name of your object.*

Comment: Hmm... your second "workaround" requires that the object be provided as a parameter. If that's acceptable, then it seems like a pointer-to-member would suit you. Are you rejecting `auto member_func = &Foo::do_something;` or is this something you are not aware of? *(This might fall under [Passing References to Member Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69338737).)*

Comment: Are you looking for `auto member_func = std::bind(&Foo::do_something, foo);`?

Comment: Thanks for the reponses @JaMiT . I was not aware the line you offered - can you share more about it? What does the type look like and how do i call it?

Comment: If you're asking about the type of `member_func` as written in `auto member_func = &Foo::do_something;` without using `auto` then it'll be `void(Foo::* member_func)() = &Foo::do_something;`, which means "`member_func` is a [pointer to a member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) of class `Foo`, taking no parameters and returning `void`".

Comment: Sadly, "why doesn't C++ have this feature?" questions are very difficult to answer.  Often the answer is simply "no one has thought about it or considered it important enough to write a proposal for it".

Comment: I suspect the reason that '<type_name>.<member_name>' for a member_name naming a member function doesn't result in a pointer is that the member function properly belongs to the type. '&<type_name>.<member_name>' (if it worked) should probably result in a function that already has 'this' bound but that would be a very awkward mess. So instead it is '<type_name>::<member_name>' and you still have to specify the instance in order to invoke it.

Comment: You should at least post correct, compilable code. What you have posted is missing a semicolon and a colon.

Comment: Thanks @heapunderrun, pointer-to-member is something I was wholly unaware of and very much appears to be the proper c++ way of doing this thing.

Comment: @AdrianMole Edited, though I question whether these syntax errors affected your ability to understand the example and help suggest a meaningful answer.

Comment: Thanks @MilesBudnek, I think this probably answers my question best.

Comment: @zebra14420 *"What does the type look like and how do i call it?"* -- These were the details I would have put in an answer, but I found that the information is already on Stack Overflow. Does this answer your question? [How can I create a pointer to a member function and call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/how-can-i-create-a-pointer-to-a-member-function-and-call-it)

Comment: For comparison with pointers to (static or non-member) functions: [How does dereferencing of a function pointer happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2795575) A key take away is that when converting a function name to a pointer to function, the `&` is optional, but not so for pointers to member functions. The relevant people simply did not prioritize giving pointer to member functions easy syntax.

Comment: Thanks again @JaMiT. Yes, you have given me very clear information on as well as references for pointers-to-member functions, I did not know about this feature of the language, and is from what I see to be the most straightforward way of referring to a member function in the context of an instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't a nonstatic member function be referred to without calling it?

The above assumption is wrong. You can refer to(point to) a member function without calling it as shown below:

```
struct C
{
    int foo()
    {
    return 5;
    }
};
int main()
{ 
      int (C::*ptr)() = &C::foo; //we created a pointer to member function without callig it

}
```

Also note that technically [a reference(as opposed to) to member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245404/reference-to-member-function) is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From what I now know I see this assumption is wrong, so I have updated the title of the question to be more in line with what my question and the example code were really asking. Had I not changed the title, I would mark your answer as correct since it is very clear and concise, but am unsure whether or not it remains relevant to the new title of my question. As it stands, I think @MilesBudnek provided the most relevant answer thus far in a comment to the original question.

Comment: @zebra14420 The simplest answer is(to your new as well as old) question is "because that's how the standard defined it or rather that's not how the standard said that it can be used for." Also I would recommend not changing the question in such a manner that it invalidates the answer( after an answer is already posted) for your future questions.